# Set model field set default to iterator

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to set `reportNr` field default to a number that iterates every time a report has been added. Is there any way to do this?

In `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models

class RapportQuerySet(models.query.QuerySet):

    def active(self):
        return self.filter()

class RapportManager(models.Manager):

    def get_queryset(self):
        return RapportQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)

    def all(self):
        return self.get_queryset().active()


class Rapport(models.Model):

    objects = RapportManager()

    reportNr    = models.TextField(blank=True, default="?")
    avd     = models.TextField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    ritningNr   = models.TextField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    enhetsNr    = models.TextField(max_length=40, null=True, blank=True)
    atgard      = models.TextField(max_length=100,null=True, blank=True)
    namn        = models.TextField(max_length=100,null=True, blank=True)
    anstNr      = models.TextField(max_length=100,null=True, blank=True)
    date        = models.DateTimeField()
    file        = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.reportNr
```

Answer (score 0):

what is the report (I do not see any relations with report), if it model instance then:
reportNr = = models.IntegerField(default=0) - must be integer
Also you can override create method

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Report, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    #Iterate the reportNr
```

Hopefully, I understand right) If not can you describe problem in details